# Microsoft Graph API- Query Failed to retrieve SharePoint list item on applying filter

Tags: api, sharepoint, graph

**Error:** Field 'Title' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' header

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Just add 'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' in the header of the request.

It works